# BUG: Emails sent with 'eml' file attachments (via Outlook Interop APIs) are not properly encoded

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop

Currently we have a VSTO application which uses the (Outlook) Primary interop assemblies.
Fundamentally the code is something like this :

```
private void AddAttachment()
{
    Outlook.MailItem mail = this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.Subject = "My EML file attachment";
    mail.Attachments.Add("a_valid_eml_file.eml", Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, attachment.FileName);
    mail.Recipients.Add("GovZ R");
    ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
}
```

The above code works perfectly for almost all of our end users. When these end users receive the sent-email, they will receive an eml file named "a_valid_eml_file.eml". When they download the received email, and save it as an eml file, the eml file will show something like this :

A. **WORKING SCENARIO**

In most of our users, the email they received (which they saved as an eml file), will have the following sequence when they open it in a text editor. The snippet below is how "a_valid_eml_file.eml" is incorporated in the sent email :

```
--B_3705415540_1653959801
Content-type: application/octet-stream; name="a_valid_eml_file.eml";
 x-mac-creator="4F50494D"
Content-ID: <B3B425FAB4333C4181D63948E31C5613@namprd18.prod.outlook.com>
Content-disposition: attachment;
    filename="a_valid_eml_file.eml"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

UmVjZWl2ZWQ6IGZyb20gSEswUFIwMU1CMjc1NS5hcGNwcmQwMS5wcm9kLmV4Y2hhbmdlbGFi
cy5jb20NCiAoMjYwMzoxMDk2OjIwMzo5Yjo6MTkpIGJ5IFNHMlBSMDFNQjMxODkuYXBjcHJk
MDEucHJvZC5leGNoYW5nZWxhYnMuY29tDQogd2l0aCBIVFRQUzsgV2VkLCAyNCBNYXIgMjAy
................
```

In the above scenario, the headers are properly formed, and transfer-encoding is set to base64. Moreover, the actual payload in the attachment eml is the base64-encoded content of the 'a_valid_eml_file.eml' attachment file. The above scenario is the expected behavior.

B. **NON-WORKING SCENARIO** -

With the same code, however, there are a few cases where the code does not work properly. When recipients of the email, download the email as an eml file and view it on a text editor, they have the following :

```
--B_3705415540_1653959801
Content-type: application/octet-stream; name="a_valid_eml_file.eml";
 x-mac-creator="4F50494D"
Content-ID: <B3B425FAB4333C4181D63948E31C5613@namprd18.prod.outlook.com>
Content-disposition: attachment;
    filename="a_valid_eml_file.eml"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

Received: from HK0PR01MB2755.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com
 (2603:1096:203:9b::19) by SG2PR01MB3189.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com
 with HTTPS; Wed, 24 Mar 202 
..................................
```

Please take note that the above snippet indicates a Content-transfer-encoding of 'base64', but the content of the attachment was never Base64-encoded.

Has anybody experienced the same issue using the Outlook Interop APIs? What possibly could have caused the non-encoding of data for some of our users?

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Are you sure it is Outlook that corrupts the message? Try to send a single message with the attachment to two recipients - one good and one bad and see if it is corrupted fro both recipients.

Comment: Hello @DmitryStreblechenko. Thank you for your response. As of this writing, I could not reproduce it in any of my machines. Also the eml file I am attaching was generated using the redemption library. I have also asked our users to send me msg files which I can use to reproduce the issue. But unfortunately, even with their msg files, I could not reproduce this in-house.

Comment: Is it always a particular user / mail server?

Comment: Thank you @DmitryStreblechenko . Your Outlook Spy and Redemption libraries are awesome by the way. I just wanted to say that. As for the same user or mail server, I will ask some of these users in a phone conversation. This is a good insight. Thank you again.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko is it possible that the eml file I am adding to the attachments is problematic? The redemption library I am using right now is version 5.10.0.4312. Do you think an update of the library might fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I still think receiving side for some reason corrupts the message. Have you tried to send the same message to the ;problematic recipient and to a Gmail mailbox so that you can compare the MIME source

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I can't reproduce it any of my machines. So I am waiting for the results of a partner who can reproduce the issue. I was reading your change log with Redemption and saw this. "Attaching an EML file created by Redemption to an Outlook message and converting that message to MIME format could produce a corrupted file since the MIME boundary generated by Redemption might not be unique enough." - Is this a possible cause of the issue? Thanks

Comment: No, that was fixed ages ago...

Answer (score 1):

It seems somebody is changing the attached item in the middle of email travelling. So, two cases are possible:

1. A corrupted file is attached on the sender's side.
2. An attached file is altered somewhere.

To check the what happened in the mail flow, let the Office 365 admin run a [message trace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200712(v=exchg.150).aspx) and analyze the results.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to check out my issue Eugene. These are good insights, I will ask them to run a message trace and probably create some special debugging binaries to check for the actual file contents just before the file is added as an attachment.